# Can I improve the performance of React set.state when updating a large 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm making a [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) as part of my quest to understand React.  Basically, a grid of `<divs>` is updated over time according to a set of rules.

I've noticed that [my implementation](http://codepen.io/thepeted/pen/aNZzdW?editors=1010)
performs at about half the speed of a [similar implementation in React](http://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/dGOOrZ)

I'm fairly inexperienced in analysing performance, but through dev tools and using `console.time()` I think I've isolated the difference in speed to the following call to `setState`:

```
advance() {
    let nextState = this.advanceGeneration();
    this.setState({gameState: nextState});
  }
```

(`advanceGeneration()` returns a 50 x 70 2D array of 0s and 1s, which represents the state of the board.)

The other example I linked to takes the approach of re-rendering the component on each new generation (rather than updating the state) - but that doesn't feel like the "React way".

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?  Have I chosen an inefficient data structure to hold the state of the grid?  Am I updating the state in an sub-optimal way?

Here is a link to the full code: http://codepen.io/thepeted/pen/aNZzdW?editors=1010

Comment: if you want  top performance, you would be a _lot_ better off using DOM methods to update the view instead of a high-level framework. since this is a learning exercise, it doesn't sound like such investment is warranted.

Comment: @dandavis That's interesting - makes sense.  I suppose initially I thought React would be well suited to this as we hear a lot about React being super fast compared to other frameworks.  As you say though, I'm trying to improve the speed as a learning exercise.

Comment: frameworks are not know for top performance, and that's not a good use-case for react since so much of the view changes each render. if you would update only a small part of a complex view, and your model was huge, react would be faster. when the view complexity is equal to (or greater) the model complexity, react is slower. see http://danml.com/intrahtml/demos/perf/ for a similar example comparison.

Comment: Chiming in regarding React and performance: web apps typically hit performance bottlenecks when updating the DOM. React tries to minimize the amount of DOM interaction by providing a high-level, declarative way to express your UI (using virtual DOM). React then computes diffs between subsequent virtual DOMs and efficiently updates the actual DOM. This is typically much faster than trying to manually re-create DOM nodes each time your data changes.

Comment: So I just delved a little deeper in to dev tools timeline (my first time really using this tool).  Main culprits are `ReactMultiChild.Mixin_updateChildren`, `ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOM` and similar DOM related things.  I'm thinking these are all called by React from the `setState` method.  Which makes sense based on your comments.